# Python-telegram-bot buttons handler invokes multiple times

Tags: python, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

When I press an inline button, handler `button_pressed` invokes multiple times. How to fix it? I need only one invocation.

```
def button_pressed(bot, update):
    query = update.callback_query

    keyboard = []
    for article in nn:
        keyboard.append([
            InlineKeyboardButton(article.title, callback_data=article.pageid)
        ])

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    bot.edit_message_text('text_here', reply_markup=reply_markup,
                          chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                          message_id=query.message.message_id)

def main():
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button_pressed))
    updater.start_polling(clean=True)
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You have to log it yourself

Comment: @Sean sorry, what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Just need to put `update.callback_query.answer()` somewhere in handler code.